# jQuery append an element more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently trying to add n number of divs to the bottom of the body, however using this code:

```
star = $('<div class="star" />');

for(i=0; i<12; i++) {
    $('body').append(star); 
}
```

results in just one div being appended to the bottom of the body. I'm guessing this is because the content of the body is not being refreshed between each iteration of the for loop, but can't figure out how to best to solve it.

Answer (score 15):

Rather than executing 12 DOM modifications, why not [multiply the string](http://www.davidflanagan.com/2009/08/string-multipli.html) and then use just one [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) call?

```
String.prototype.times = function(n) {
    return Array.prototype.join.call({length: n+1}, this);
};

var star = '<div class="star" />'.times(12);
$('body').append(star);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/AdZkz/)

---

#### Fix for your original method

If you want to stay with your method, you'll need to call the `$` function inside the loop so that a distinct jQuery object is created on each iteration. I'm guessing this is slower, but it'd work.

```
star = '<div class="star" />';
var body = $('body');

for ( i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
    body.append($(star));
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hans/YXBAP/)

Comment: +1 hans , nice answer, i forgot this performance issue in my answer.

Comment: or shorter: $('body').append(new Array(12).join('<div class="star" />'));

Comment: Why not `"<div class='star' />".repeat(12)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
$('body').append(new Array(13).join('<div class="star" />'));
```

Comment: This will add 11 divs, not 12. (The argument to `join()` is the separator, which is added in between each of the 12 undefined elements in the array.)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var star = '<div class="star" />SomeTest</div>';

for(i=0; i<12; i++) {
    $('body').append(star); 
}
```

Comment: @richard , as others suggested , you can do the looping and append at the end of it , don't append 12 times , its expensive dom operation

Answer (score 0):

It should be noted that using FOR loop is worse than iterating with jquery .each() function, as FOR loop is not asynchronous and therefore much much slower on bigger scale, since each() instances run side by side, when FOR loop waits for each iteration to complete before continueing to next iteration.

(Can't just comment because of 50 rep requirement.)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    star = '<div class="star" />';
    var body = $('body');

    for ( i = 0; i < 12; i++ ) {
        body.append($(star));
    }
});
```

```css
.star {  border: 1px solid black; height: 20px; width: 100px;margin-bottom:1px }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```